# Visual Studio change C++ class file name capitalization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need to **change the capitalization of a C++ class file in MS Visual Studio 2015**.
I managed to refactor my code, but I still can't rename my class files. (.h + .cpp)

I'm getting the following error: 
**There is already a file with the same name in this location.**
note: I'm trying to rename from Solution explorer.

I renamed the files from file explorer, made  clean and rebuild.
In git and in file explorer I have the right file names, but in **VS Solution explorer** I have the old ones.

Any idea how to solve this, to see the right file name in Solution explorer or
just simply rename from VS.

Comment: Yes.  Rename the file _whatever.h then rename it back to whatever.h.

Comment: @Robinson Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried this before. It worked except the old file name appeared in the solution explorer.

Comment: The default setting for the Windows file system is for it to be case-insensitive. A file named `Foo.h` is the same as `foo.h`. That's why you get the "same name" error. Besides that, even if you capitalize class names, I recommend you don't do that for the files.

Comment: @Gabeeka I meant do it in the solution explorer.  I just tried it on one of my files and it works fine.  Basically you just want to force it to update the vxproj file, which you can edit in a text editor btw (it contains the file list).

Comment: @Robinson I did it there (probably I wasn't clear enough). Anyway I tried a trick which solved my problem. Excluded the files then I added them back as existing items.

Comment: vcxproj and vcxproj.filter files to be editted

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Aw forgot about that. Is there a way to avoid the above mentioned hacks in the future and just simply rename in the solution explorer?

Comment: @Gabeeka the easy option is to not have files who's names differ by case